# Sunnah on licking fingers after eating

Tags: hadith

We know it is sunnah to lick fingers after eating a dish, what if one had the thought and sunnah in his mind, about to lick fingers but after eating he was not able to do it as his mother had called him. He had the knowledge of sunnah in his mind but due to some reasons he was not able to perform it.

Is this kufr? He hadn't intended to reject sunnah or perform kufr.

Comment: Relax. It’s not the end of the world if you didn’t complete that Sunnah. Sunnah’s aren’t mandatory, but they’re recommended to follow because the Prophet (saws) did them and one will earn rewards in doing so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "X" kufr (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/70271/is-x-kufr-reference-question)

Answer (score 0):

Sunnah, is when you do something, you get rewards for it and if you don't do it, you don't get anything (Reward or sin). However this doesn't reach to compulsory.
(e.g lick fingers after eat, etc)

So Nope, it's not kufr (if you don't do it). As long as you believe the sunnah.